# How can I remove right sidebar on single woocommerce product page?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-theming

By default on the right side of single product it shows sidebar. The point is that we need side bar only on the Shop page where are located all products. It includes all filters as well as rated products. But on the single product description page we want to remove right side bar. Because in that page it shows only rated products in sidebar. It was there by default. Is there any way to remove it from that page?

Answer (score 2):

Currently in the file `templates/single-product.php` the sidebar is called

```
/**
* woocommerce_sidebar hook.
*
* @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
```

Therefore you can remove it with `remove_action('woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);` or wrap it to make sure it only affects single product pages:

```
if ( is_product() ) {
   remove_action('woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);
}
```

Here is the documentation for other conditional tags if you need to get rid of it somewhere else and it uses the same action: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Answer (score 2):

This solution i create in 2021 works very good (sorry my english)

```
/*Single product page no sidebar*/
#blog #sidebar {
    display: none;
}
#blog .col-md-push-3 {
    left: unset;
}
#blog .col-md-9 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

put this code in main page css code

Visit https://rgrepairofice.ddns.net/loja/gta-v

to check result, if you like it do what i said above

Gaspar Pereira, from rgrepairofice

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the theme that you are using, as sometimes there is even an option in the theme options or the Customizer for changing layouts to different pages.

Through code, you could probably replace the single-product.php with a page template file that has no sidebar and then reinsert the missing WooCommerce tags, so that WooCommerce does it's magic on the page.

Comment: It's a new theme.  We tried to change some code but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Could you mention the name of the theme, if it's in wordpress.org?

Answer (score 0):

You could try going to [project-name]/wp-content/themes/[theme-name]/woocommerce/single-product.php and look for this line:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
```

And remove the line or comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can also **remove the sidebar with CSS only** and not touching the PHP files if you don't want to!
For example the following simple CSS codes work like a charm with the *Storefront theme* (currently that I'm writing this, the theme version is 4.1.0)

```
.single-product #primary {
    width: 100%;
}
.single-product #secondary {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You won't be able to accomplish this by default with WooCommerce and WordPress. However, it's easy to accomplish if you're not looking to dive into code. A popular choice is [Widget Visibility by Jetpack](https://jetpack.com/support/widget-visibility/). If you're looking to dive into code, I recommend asking a new question with more details on what you tried to do already.

Comment: By using Widget Visibility you could hide a widget, but not hide an entire sidebar and extend the page template to full width. Also, installing JetPack just for this would be a major overkill.

Comment: @vlood Yes but the question is non-dev related and it's difficult to make sense of the question. The question does not specifically state wanting full-width nor what theme is being used. We're assuming it but we also don't know the theme being used.